# Downloading data using PycURL in Canopy under mac os High Sierra failed

Tags: curl, jupyter-notebook, canopy, pycurl, macos-high-sierra

I tried to write two functions in python which can be used for downloading data from sites and save those as csv files.

The functions are:

```
def get_site_url( site_number='01589440', date_from="2008-01-01",date_to="2017-12-31" ): 
# input: site_number is a string
# the parameters in the url can have different formats. cb_00065 is the same as parameterCd=00060

#url = 'https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv/cb_00065=on&format=rdb&site_no=%speriod=&begin_date=%s\
#&end_date=%s&siteStatus=all'%(site_number, date_from, date_to)

url = "https://nwis.waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/uv/?parameterCd=00060,00065&format=rdb&site_no=%s&period=&begin_date=%s\
&end_date=%s&siteStatus=all"%(site_number, date_from, date_to)
return url

def download_data_from_url( url, savename='test.csv' ):
''' 
One can download data with a different method that supports resume. If data is two large then it takes
lot of time and the connection to the server might be interrupted.
'''

buffer = BytesIO()
c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
c.perform()
c.close()

body = buffer.getvalue() # Body is a byte string.
with open( savename, 'w' ) as output:
    output.write( body.decode('utf-8')) # We have to know the encoding in order to print it to a text file
```

Using this two function as next:

```
FirstExcUrl = get_site_url()
download_data_from_url(FirstExcUrl, '%s.csv'%'01589440')
```

produced the error:

```
errorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-f460d226bec2> in <module>()
      1 FirstExcUrl = get_site_url()
----> 2 download_data_from_url(FirstExcUrl, '%s.csv'%'01589440')

<ipython-input-3-e6e6e1be72e0> in download_data_from_url(url, savename)
     19     c.setopt(c.URL, url)
     20     c.setopt(c.WRITEDATA, buffer)
---> 21     c.perform()
     22     c.close()
     23 

error: (1, 'Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl')
```

It is an output of a jupyter note book was started from an enthought Canopy editor window. I installed both curl and PycURL from Canpy package manager. The curl version got installed is: 7.58.0-1 and the version of PycURL got installed is: 7.19.5-5.

Any help, suggestion or solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, we do not currently build libcurl with SSL support. You could use another python package (for example requests) which does support SSL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!